# How to use usb token pkcs#11 certificate for Nodejs https client?

Tags: node.js, https, pkcs#11

If you have a client certificate pair (self signed) then you can make a https get call like this in nodejs;

```
request.get({
      url: 'https://example.com/list',
      key: certificate.key,
      cert: certificate.cert,
      ca: certificate.ca
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      ...
    });
```

How will we write this code if we are storing certificate pair in a hardware PKI token like [ePass2003](https://www.ftsafe.com/onlinestore/product?id=3)?

Will we read key & cert from PKI token? or

Will we use another method?

Please note that, in this scenario all clients must have a valid certificate in order to connect server.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you talking about Web Login / Authentication using client's registered certificate? If yes, please check if it helps!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885